# View takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django

In the main `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^request/(Req_.*)/someoperation/',include(someoperation.urls))
```

In `someoperation.urls`:

```
url(r'^query$', queryPage),
```

`queryPage` looks like:

```
def queryPage(request, request_id):
    #somestuff
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

The URL getting opened is:

```
myhost:myport/request/Req_ABCXYZ/someoperation/query
```

But I get this error:

```
ec/2014 05:41:18] ERROR [django.request:215] Internal Server Error: /request/Req_ABCXYZ/someoperation/query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/xyz/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: queryPage() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What could be going on? I'm sure `Req_.*` matches `Req_ABCXYZ`; so it should be getting passed on to the view `queryPage`.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, you're only passing one variable to the function, when it's expecting two. Assuming that request_id is required for your function to work you'll have to modify your urls.py so that it captures the request_id from the URL and passes it to the view.

This simple example should give you an idea how to go about it:

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'base.views.index'),
)
```

*views.py*

```
def index(request, slug=None):
    if slug is not None:
        return HttpResponse(slug)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("No slug provided")
```

It's basically a case of wrapping your regex in  (?INSERT_REGEX_HERE) tag, so in your case it would be:

```
(?P<request_id>Req_.*)
```

Comment: Django is supposed to capture the URL even without trying to name the parameter. Naming the captured elements fixes it though, thanks! I don't know why the other way doesn't work.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. You had the brackets enclosing all of Req_.* whereas what you wanted was:

`url(r'^request/Req_(.*)/someoperation/',include(someoperation.urls))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
url(r'^request/(?P<request_id>Req_.*)/someoperation/',include(someoperation.urls))
```